# How to deal with crowded floor drain?

Tags: drain, condensate

## Problem

My 3" basement floor drain has 10 pounds of... stuff in a 5 pound bag:

- ¾" air handler condensate drain (hard-piped to air handler)
- ¾" furnace condensate drain (open air gap)
- 1" washer drain pan (from upstairs)
- 1½" water heater drain pan
- ⅜" water softener main (discharge) drain line
- ⅜" water softener overflow drain line

[image: Pipes crowded in floor drain]

[image: Pipes out of floor drain]

[image: Pipes from HVAC]

---

There are a few problems:

1. The concrete is not smooth and has a slight lip where it meets the (roughly cut) floor drain.
2. Not all of the pipes are completely over the floor drain.
3. Some of the pipes are not affixed -- the water heater drain pan pipe can easily be bumped and no longer terminate over the floor drain.
4. I'm considering adding a drain pan under the water softener, too.
5. I will likely be adding an additional drain for a humidifier, making the situation worse.

**What is the best way to remedy this?**

## Proposal

I understand that most drains like these cannot be hard-plumbed, in order to prevent discharge from one appliance backing up into another.

The furnace condensate drain actually has a small air-gap where it drains into the vertical ¾" PVC. So this could presumably be combined with the air conditioner condensate drain.

Here's what I'm considering (numbered according to the above):

1. Use a diamond blade on my multi-tool to cut down the lip around the drain.
2. Add an elbow or tee to the end of the water heater drain line so it is directed down the drain.
3. Attach the drain line to the floor with a clamp.
4. Tee the new softener drain pan into the water heater drain pan line.
5. Add a couple of open tees (perhaps with a short standpipe) along the water heater drain pan, into which the other lines can drain.

[image: Proposed arrangement]

One slight concern is the high volume of discharge from the softener drain line. I might leave that one right in the floor drain.

Comment: Most of that isn't compliant as it was, due to lack of an actual air gap (pipes poking down into a drain is not an air gap, as the drain can back up and remove whatever "gap" you expect to be there "normally." Put in a slot drain and put the discharge end of the pipes 2 pipe diameters above the floor level.

Comment: @Ecnerwal not sure that'll work for the WH drain pan...well, not unless the entire WH and pan get raised up.

Comment: I suspect there is an easier solution that doesn't involve a concrete saw.